# Debugging jQueryUI Interactions

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm trying to use jQuery UI on a complex layout to get some of the interactions (drag, drop, sort, resize). So far, with only `sortable` I'm running into a CSS issue when the action is started but I cannot debug it because as soon as I release the block I'm dragging the support classes disappear as expected.

My question is not so much how to solve this problem but how I can debug this type of errors (mocking drag and drops, for example) as I know I will have plenty developing all the interactions.

In case you want to have a look at the issue, you can have a look at the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jcano/t2bd3cyu/8/). The sortable is activated without parameters

```
$(".track-content").sortable()
```

and the issue is that when a block moves, the others "fall" out of the container div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chrome has many types of breakpoints that you can use. https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging#breakpoints-on-javascript-event-listeners

I might suggest a DOM Breakpoint or Event Listner Breakpoint for your example.

Try right clicking on `<div class="track-content ui-sortable">` in the Elements panel and choosing `Break on... > Subtree modifications`. That pauses execution at some interesting points and will allow you to inspect styles.

Comment: I used Chrome's DevTools before, but only to debug style or JS. I didn't know about the DOM Breakpoints. I'll try it out!